# Want to use either of the 2 different .js files depending upon webpack build mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

This is my first question here.

I have two scripts: **script.js and script-dev.js**

Both scripts are located in **'static'** folder(I am using NUXTJS)

Now, when webpack production build is used, ONLY `script.js` should be used and `script-dev.js` should be excluded/not used (sorry if i am using any incorrect term)

Similarly, for webpack development build, ONLY `script-dev.js` should be used and `script.js` should be excluded/not used.

(I am doing so because I will be using two diff API Urls in both files and `script-dev.js` will be used only for testing code in development. )

I have a nuxt.config.js file in root folder.

Can anyone please help me how can I modify the nuxt.config.js (or any other way you know) to achieve the above result.

here is my current nuxt.config.js and I have extended the webpack config as shown below (sorry for the improper formatting):

```js
export default {
  telemetry: false,
  mode: 'universal',
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000,
  },
  env: {
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
  },
  serverMiddleware: [
    {
      path: '/r',
      handler: '~/api/redirector.js',
    },
  ],
  build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isDev) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /.js$/,
          exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/script.js')],
        })
      } else {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /.js$/,
          exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/script-dev.js')],
        })
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: It's simpler to use an environment variable for this instead of two different files just to change an API URL.

Comment: Rather than apologizing, please fix your code directly next time. Also, what is not working here? PS: you should not put JS code into `static`, this directory is used for public purposes, like sharing a `.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks  @tony19 ! But I want the API URL to change on build time.

Comment: Yeah @kissu will keep that in mind. I fixed it using copywebpack plugin.
Actually, the script is for in-app widgets and is publicly available. Hence, intentionally put into `static`